# Bootstrap column heights causing things to jumble around

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got a page of products, and some of them might have extra rows. Regardless of that, my goal is to have every product display across the page, left to right, top to bottom.

See this example: http://jsbin.com/lijisa

If you modify the JSON data so that each product has two numbers in the `variations` array, everything lines up perfectly.

How can I get all the columns to be a standard height, without actually setting a hard height value?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is known as a "masonry layout" there are a few libraries that will allow you to do such a thing

Salvattore
http://salvattore.com/

Masonry
http://masonry.desandro.com/

I also found this achieving the same effect using column-width
http://www.bootply.com/118335

Comment: Quite the opposite. I just need the heights on the shorter columns to expand so all column divs are the exact same height.

Comment: In that case, loop over the divs with javascript getting all the heights, then set all the heights to the highest value, you wont be able to do this with pure css without specifying a fixed height

http://jsbin.com/lirubipawo

Comment: That works. Though I was hoping to use a CSS-only fix, but if I can't find one, this definitely does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `hidden/visible` helper classes combined with `clearfix`, to reset your rows only on appropriate devices, like so:

Example: http://www.bootply.com/YpH56xyzDB

The hidden/visible aspect lets you clearfix between specific columns only when on the right device.

Comment: that's fine - if you put it on every third/fourth column, it will effectively set the whole row to the height of the tallest column

Comment: oh, your comment is gone:)

Comment: Sorry, I removed it because I figured I'd test it first.. which I haven't yet. I don't know how many columns are spit out, AND the number of columns varies based on browser width. I'm using a Handlebars loop so I'm not sure if I can keep an index count and spit out a clearfix once in a while. Might be tricky.

Comment: Ah. Yeah, may be trickier than doing it with js afterall, but it's probably the best CSS-only option.